# Image Assets not showing up in programmatic Layout in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uikit

I've added a jpeg file called 'Black' in my assets folder. When I type:

```
let appLogo = UIImageView(image: Black)
appLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 200, height: 200)
view.addSubview(appLogo)
```

for the first line, it says:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Black'

I can't seem to get the picture to come up. It's as if the jpeg isn't even in the assets folder.

Comment: Maybe the asset folder isn't configured for the Target that you're building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use the name of `UIImage` directly instead use **`UIImage(named: "Your_Image.extension")`**

````
let appLogo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Black.jpeg"))
appLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 200, height: 200)
view.addSubview(appLogo)```
````